# postfix: lost connection after CONNECT/EHLO/unknown from unknown

Tags: postfix, email-server, failed

seeing following error message while trying to send email via postfix on Centos 7 while I can receive and download messages not seeing any errors

```
postfix/smtpd[24532]: connect from unknown[5.31.230.96]
postfix/smtpd[24532]: disconnect from unknown[5.31.230.96]
```

or

```
postfix/smtpd[24366]: connect from unknown[5.31.230.96]
postfix/smtpd[24366]: warning: Wrapper-mode request dropped from unknown[5.31.230.96] for service submission. TLS context initial...our logs.
postfix/smtpd[24366]: disconnect from unknown[5.31.230.96]
postfix/smtpd[24366]: connect from unknown[5.31.230.96]
postfix/smtpd[24366]: warning: Wrapper-mode request dropped from unknown[5.31.230.96] for service submission. TLS context initial...our logs.
postfix/smtpd[24366]: disconnect from unknown[5.31.230.96]
postfix/smtpd[24369]: connect from unknown[5.31.183.32]
postfix/smtpd[24369]: lost connection after EHLO from unknown[5.31.183.32]
postfix/smtpd[24369]: disconnect from unknown[5.31.183.32]
```

or

```
postfix/smtpd[24371]: connect from unknown[unknown]
postfix/smtpd[24371]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[unknown]
postfix/smtpd[24371]: disconnect from unknown[unknown]
```

postfix/dovecot configuration as per article https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/mailserver-with-virtual-users-and-domains-using-postfix-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-6-vps/

Comment: Are you sending via 465 or 587?

Comment: I am using port 587

Comment: anyone, please ?

Comment: Postconf  output?

Comment: postconf output under the following link http://pastebin.com/0aaaBst8

Comment: for me this time it was resolved by reconfiguring mail clients apparently.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had said that the IP addresses listed above were the expected attempts at sending emails. If your issue is resolved then you should write up an answer and accept it or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

This fix is for Redhat8 or Rocky Linux

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_application_name     = smtpd
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
```